# Change the sender email of logwatch on RH Linux

Tags: linux, sendmail, logwatch

Im running logwatch on red hat 7
it sends mails using root@localhost.localdomain
however, the email from localhost.localdomain is not received at the recipient because localhost.localdomain is not registered.
I want to change logwatch or mail to send from for example myname@registereddomain.com instead of root@localhost.localdomain.
Can anyone help me?
I have already tried changing logwatch.conf with MailFrom = myname@registereddomain.com but did not work.
Logwatch is using mail (not sendmail) .

Answer (score 2):

### [cf/README - Who Am I?](https://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/whoami.html)

You may define `confDOMAIN_NAME` in `sendmail.mc`:

```
define(`confDOMAIN_NAME', `Real.Host.Name')dnl
```

P.S. After changing `sendmail.mc` generate new `sendmail.cf`.

Answer (score 1):

In your `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` add the following lines at the end:

```
LOCAL_CONFIG
DjReal.Host.Name
```

Where `Real.Host.Name` is the real host name of the machine. `$j` is the macro that holds the hostname. After that rebuild `sendmail.cf` and restart sendmail. In Debian you do this by running `sendmailconfig`. In CentOS you first run `/etc/mail/mail` and then `service sendmail restart`.

Comment: The cleaner way is to define confDOMAIN_NAME as described in file cf/README section "who Am I".

Comment: Oh some times you can't teach an old dog new tricks :)

Comment: @AndrzejA.Filip Please submit this as a separate answer for better visibility and sweet, sweet, delicious upvotes!

Comment: @AaronCopley done