# How to fix "unable to qualify my own domain name (myhost) -- using short name"?

Tags: domain-name-system, email, smtp, sendmail, ubuntu-12.10

and yes, I have

```
127.0.0.1   localhost myhost.mydomain.eu myhost.domain2.eu localhost.localdomain
127.0.1.1   myhost
```

in hosts file. What is wrong? Sendmail started to put this error into log.

> May  9 19:08:54 myhost sm-mta[17103]: unable to qualify my own domain
>   name (myhost) -- using short name

Is this configuration OK?

Comment: What is "this error"?

Comment: unable to qualify my own domain name (myhost) — using short name

Comment: I didn't receive this error at the beginning - It must be that I deleted something from somewhere

Comment: @Gnouc however sendmail works almost entirely OK

Comment: "unable to qualify my own domain name (myhost)" - What tool you use to troubleshoot? Ping command?

Comment: this is error from mail.err

Comment: Would you mind posting the error and your sendmail config?

Comment: @Gnouc this is this error, I added to question. (possibly I've just found solution)

Comment: This question and its answer were exactly what I was looking for, so it should be reopened. The title states the question correctly. The body text asks whether the answer lies in modifying /etc/hosts, and if so, how. The answer makes it clear that this is indeed the case. The body text could be cleared up a little.

Comment: In CentOS 6, this error can be found in /var/log/maillog and the solution (which could be explained better) makes a big difference. I've been working on Dovecot+Postfix+Sendmail for 2 days now and thanks to this crazy question, this is the first time I'm able to email my own server. Goodbye Gmail ;-)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Sendmail: short host name to FQDN via /etc/hosts entry

Reorder your `/etc/hosts` file entries:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain
127.0.1.1   myhost.mydomain.eu myhost.domain2.eu myhost
```

It should qualify `myhost` to `myhost.mydomain.eu` (the leftmost name in `/etc/hosts` line with `myhost`)

Comment: what about localhost? might be after this? why? what are the rules?

Comment: @Andzrej A.Filip really this way? I have seen many configuration but not this one, can you say anything about it?

Comment: this works! great. However I had changed 127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain to 127.0.0.1   localhost myhost.mydomain.eu before because my SMTP has introduced himself as localhost.localdomain : I am afraid this problem will come back now. What do you think about it?

Comment: If you want to change how your SMTP server announces itself change the $j macro as [described here](http://serverfault.com/a/505546/25640)

Comment: As I understand when sendmail uses /etc/hosts file to get Fully Quallified Domain Name (FQDN) it gets leftmost **name** from line with the short host name.

Comment: I have tested and it looks like indeed myhost.mydomain.eu is taken to introducing themself by my sendmail (I didn't change $j macr but thanks adamo), previously I was listed on Spamhaus due to my SMTP EHLOong as localhost.localdomain. THANK YOU

Comment: IMHO changing $j (solution for sendmail ONLY) should not be be first choice in most situations.

Answer (score 0):

The issue can be resolved by entering the exchange server and mail router ip and domain information in your `/etc/hosts file`. See below:

```
#######mail server

ipofexchangeserver   exchangeservername.domain.local  mailhost

ipofmailrouter       mailrouter mailrouter.domain
```

Example:

```
172.18.18.400    sampleexvs   sampleexvs.samplegroup.com   mailhost

172.18.68.432    mailrouter   mailrouter.samplegroup.net
```